# Group array by specific key - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to group by key this array:

```
$arr = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'a'],
    ['id' => 2, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'a-child'],
    ['id' => 3, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'a-child-2'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'c'],
];
```

To be like this:

```
['id' => 1, 'name' => 'a', 'child' => [
    ['id' => 2, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'a-child'],
    ['id' => 3, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'a-child-2'],
]],
['id' => 4, 'name' => 'c'],
```

or group them by specific key, which element will be a parent.
I am using `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for 1 level deep.

```
$arr = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'a'],
    ['id' => 2, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'a-child'],
    ['id' => 3, 'parent' => 1, 'name' => 'a-child-2'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'c'],
];


$new = [];

foreach($arr as $key => $row) {
    if(!isset($row['parent'])) $new[$row['id']] = $row;
}

foreach($arr as $key => $child) {
    if(isset($child['parent'])) { 
        $new[$child['parent']]['child'][] = $child;
    }
}

print_r($new);
```